# Custom UI Elements not updating in LazyVGrid

Tags: swiftui

I have created a custom element I am calling `Slide`. I have a `LazyVGrid` that is displaying my `Slide` elements. My issue is that when I update the data array that my grid is using, the `Slide` elements are not updating.

**Scenario:**
User clicks on the options button on a `Slide` and changes the `Slide` color, I am then updating the data array  but the `Slide` element doesn't update despite the data being correct (I have verified this by adding `Text(slide.color)` into the `LazyVGrid` which displays the newly set color as expected)

My Suspicions:
I am assuming it doesn't update because I have something wrong in the `Slide` struct, I am quite new to SwiftUI so I am learning as I go. I must also mention that this loads and displays correctly when I first display the view, the only issue is that it doesn't update when I update the `SlideStructure`.

Here is the Code:

```
struct ShowSongFile : View {
@EnvironmentObject var SlideStructure : SlidesModel
@State var selectedSlide : SplaySlide? = nil
var columns = [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 320))]
var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .trailing, spacing: 20) {
            ForEach(SlideStructure.SongSlides, id:\.id) { slide in
                if slide.id == selectedSlide?.id {
                    Slide(IsSelected:true, SlideData: slide)
                 
                } else {
                    Slide(IsSelected:false, SlideData: slide)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            selectSlide(Slide: slide)
                        }
                }
            }
        }.onAppear(perform: loadSelectedFile)
    }
}
```

**Here is the Slide File which also shows how I am setting the colours for the slides:**

```
struct Slide : View {
@State var EnableSlideEditing : Bool? = false
@State var IsSelected : Bool = false
@State var SlideData : SplaySlide
@EnvironmentObject var SlideStructure : SlidesModel

var body : some View {
    VStack {
        Group{
            VStack(alignment: .center) {
                let editor = TextEditor(text: $SlideData.lyric)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .padding()
                let text = Text(SlideData.lyric)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .frame(width: 320.0, height: 160.0)
                if EnableSlideEditing ?? false {
                    editor
                } else {
                    text
                }
                
                Group {
                    HStack {
                        Text(SlideData.slideType)
                            .padding(.leading, 5.0)
                        Spacer()
                        MenuButton(label: Image(systemName: "ellipsis.circle")) {
                            Button("Edit Slide Text", action: {EnableSlideEditing?.toggle()})
                            Divider()
                            Menu("Slide Type") {
                                Button("Verse", action: {SlideType(Type: "Verse", ColorHex: "#f57242")})
                                Button("Chorus", action: {SlideType(Type: "Chorus", ColorHex: "#0068bd")})
                                Button("Pre-Chorus", action: {SlideType(Type: "Pre-Chorus", ColorHex: "#02ad96")})
                                Button("Tag", action: {SlideType(Type: "Tag", ColorHex: "#ad027d")})
                                Button("Bridge", action: {SlideType(Type: "Bridge", ColorHex: "#02ad96")})
                            }
                            Menu("Transitions") {
                                Button("Option 1", action: {})
                                Button("Option 2", action: {})
                            }
                            Divider()
                            Button("Delete Slide", action: {})
                            Button("Duplicate Slide", action: {})
                        }
                        .menuButtonStyle(BorderlessButtonMenuButtonStyle())
                        .frame(alignment: .trailing)
                        .padding(.trailing, 5.0)
                        .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 320, height: 20, alignment: .leading)
                .background(Color.init(hex: SlideData.slideBorderColorHex))
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 320, height: 180, alignment: .bottomLeading)
        .background(IsSelected ? Color.accentColor : .black)
        .cornerRadius(10)
    }
}

func SlideType(Type:String, ColorHex: String) {
    for (index, slide) in SlideStructure.SongSlides.enumerated() {
        if slide.id == self.SlideData.id {
            SlideStructure.SongSlides[index].slideBorderColorHex = ColorHex
            SlideStructure.SongSlides[index].slideType = Type
            ShowSongFile.main?.SongFile.slides = SlideStructure.SongSlides
            ShowSongFile.main!.SongFile.SaveSongToDisk()
          }
      }
   }
}
```

**SlideStructure: (SlideModel)**

```
class SlidesModel : ObservableObject {
@Published var SongSlides : [SplaySlide] = []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are too many missing parts to be able to test any particular solution, so I will take a guess.
In `ShowSongFile` you could try :

```
LazyVGrid(columns: columns, alignment: .trailing, spacing: 20) {
    ForEach(SlideStructure.SongSlides, id:\.id) { slide in
        Slide(SlideData: slide)  // <--- here
            .onTapGesture {
                selectSlide(Slide: slide)
            }
            .background(slide.id == selectedSlide?.id ? Color.accentColor : .black)  // <--- here
    }
```

and adjust `Slide` accordingly, that is, remove `IsSelected` and `.background(IsSelected ? Color.accentColor : .black)`.

P.S: your naming and case of your variables and functions makes
reading your code less than appealing.